# How to add typehints to function in functions.php when argument is an object?

Tags: php, functions, oop

I have a function that is defined in functions.php of my theme and it makes use of the WP_User object.  My problem is how do I let the PHP interpreter aware of its use.

This doesn't work

```
//function declaration breaks
function myFunc(int $userId, WP_User $wpUser) :void { 
    //do stuff
}
add_action("wp_login", myFunc, 10, 2);
```

But this does

```
//function declaration works
function myFunc($userId, $wpUser) :void { 
    //do stuff
}

add_action("wp_login", myFunc, 10, 2);
```

due to coding standards I need the type hinted version to work.

What is the best way of making PHP aware of the WP_User class?

By using `require_once`? or some other method as I am not sure if requiring files from `wp_includes` folder is a good idea.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: which coding standards are you referring to? And what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Your syntax looks fine to me, unless you're in a namespaced file?

Comment: `function myFunc(int $userId, WP_User $wpUser)` doesn't work because the first argument is a string (`$user_login`) and not integer. See [`wp_login`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/). And the "myFunc" in your `add_action()` call should be put it quotes (`'myFunc'`).